# Can't get a table from a web page

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to try to get the whole table of all 2000 companies from this URL:

*https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#tab:overall.*

This is the code I have written:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

html_content = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#header:position')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,7), index = [0])

row_marker = 0
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
   column_marker = 0
   columns = row.find_all('td')

   for column in columns:
      new_table.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = column.get_text()
      column_marker += 1
new_table
```

In the result, I get only the names of the columns, but not the table itself.

How can I get the whole table.

Comment: If the page uses javascript to populate the table, BeautifulSoup doesn't run it. Maybe take a look at [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is generated via `javascript`, so you can must `selenium` to mimic a browser and scroll movements, and then parse the page source with `beautiful soup`, or, in some cases, like this one, you can access those values by querying their ajax API:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}

target = 'https://www.forbes.com/ajax/list/data?year=2017&uri=global2000&type=organization'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    data = json.loads(s.get(target).text)

print([x['name'] for x in data[:5]])
```

**Output (first 5 items)**:

```
['3M', '3i Group', '77 Bank', 'AAC Technologies Holdings', 'ABB']
```